# Firebase Cloud Massage

Tags: firebase

Мне нужно отправить уведомление Cloud Massage на телефон с Firebase и при нажатии на уведомление открывалось приложение с лентой этих уведомлений. 
Вопрос, как вытащить текст уведомлений, чтобы в дальнейшем его использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Механизм обработки Push уведомлений при закрытом и открытом приложении сильно отличается:

- В первом случае уведомление попадает от сервера в ОС смартфона и отображается пользователю, само приложение ничего не делает. По клику на уведомление открывается приложение, и тогда уже можно обработать полученные данные. И это не обязательно только текст, уведомления могут содержать скрытые от пользователя данные, доступные самому приложению.
- Во втором случае, когда приложение открыто, то оно сразу получает уведомления, а система их не отображает (поэтому если нужно, то придётся отображение уведомлений реализовывать самостоятельно).

ОС не уточняли, поэтому вот ссылки на доки по обработке полученных уведомлений для двух платформ. **iOS**:

- [FCM iOS: receive notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive)
- [iOS Remote Notifications Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/)

**Android**:

- [FCM Android: receive notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)
- [Android Remote Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)